# Referencing multiple methods using one delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm currently `sandpitting` delegates.
In the following example does `dd` reference `p.m` *and* `p.n` ?
Can I add another line to run `p.m` again after adding `p.n` ? Or do I need to implement `d dd = p.m;` again?

```
class Program
{
    private delegate int d(int x);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p;
        p = new Program();

        d dd = p.m;//d dd = new d(p.m);
        Console.WriteLine(dd(3).ToString());

        dd += p.n;//dd += new d(p.n);
        Console.WriteLine(dd(3).ToString());

        //<<is there now a quick way to run p.m ?

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private int m(int y)
    {
        return y * y;
    }
    private int n(int y)
    {
        return y * y - 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: this might prove somewhat useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173175(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What is your overall goal with this? if you want to just run p.m after p.n has been added, you should do as @daryal suggest.

Comment: @Ric it did prove useful: thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, after first assignment (`d dd = this.m;`), all assignment made using `+=` will also be called.

You may just remove a method, using `-=`, refer to the following sample;

```
d dd = p.m;//d dd = new d(p.m);
Console.WriteLine(dd(3).ToString()); //calls p.m

dd += p.n;//dd += new d(p.n);
Console.WriteLine(dd(3).ToString()); //calls boths p.m and p.n

dd -= p.n;
Console.WriteLine(dd(3).ToString()); // only calls p.m
```

Comment: +1 ok - so I was guessing that it was something like a list of methods, referenced by the delegate and I'd be able to somehow choose which one to invoke. Turns out it's all or nothing - whichever methods are pointed at by the delegate will get run

Comment: @whytheq you are right, you may think the delegate as a pointer to method(s).

Answer (score 2):

```
//is there now a quick way to run p.m ?
```

Yes, in addition to daryal's post, this could be done (while still maintaining a multicast delegate) via:

```
p.GetInvocationList()[0].DynamicInvoke(new object[] { 3 });
```